# HERE How to get more than 100 places with discover

Tags: api, here-api, geocoder

I'm developing a system to show the user all the activities in an area, i'm using Developer HERE api's using the discover api request. Discover limits at 100 activities per request and this is fine but i would like to know if it is possible to ask for the rest of the places in a second api call to get them all.

Like there are 130 resturants near my user, i first ask for the first 100 and then for the other 30 so in this way the user gets the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

The discover API does not currently support pagination to serve this requirement.
This is explained here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/migration_guide/migration-places/topics-api/search.html

However, you can implement pagination on client side from the discover result. There is a sample that I have created for purely reference that might help you.
Code Snippet:

```js
function getResultCount(arr) {
            let arrLength = arr.length;
            let noOfPagination = arrLength / 10;
            let reminder = arrLength % 10;
            if (reminder > 0) {
                noOfPagination = noOfPagination + 1;
            }
            createPagination(noOfPagination);
        }
```

Complete Sample Example: https://jsfiddle.net/raj0665/f5w12u9s/4/